# CSS How would I get these checkboxes into a grid layout

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-grid

I want to set these checkboxes up in a table style grid without using a table in HTML. I was trying CSS but it seems like I will need to add a class to each tag for each slot.

Is there a way I can avoid this?

```
<div class = permissions_grid>
          <div class="column_labels"></div>
            <label>All Members</label>
            <label>Relevant Experience</label>
            <label>HUB Moderators</label>
            <label>Invited Members</label>
          </div>
          <div class="row_edit_documents">
            <label>Edit Documents</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="all-D" name="edit_docs" value="all">
            <input type="checkbox" class="relevant" name="edit_docs" value="relevant">
            <input type="checkbox" class="moderators" name="edit_docs" value="moderators">
            <input type="checkbox" class="invited" name="edit_docs" value="invited" checked>
          </div>
          <div class = "row_add_categories">
            <label>Add Feedback Categories</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="all-C" name="add_cat" value="all" checked>
            <input type="checkbox" class="relevant" name="add_cat" value="relevant">
            <input type="checkbox" class="moderators" name="add_cat" value="moderators">
            <input type="checkbox" class="invited" name="add_cat" value="invited">
          </div>
          <div class = "row_move_com_cat">
            <label>Move Comments and Categories</label>
            <span class="x">X</span>
            <input type="checkbox" class="relevant" name="move" value="relevant">
            <input type="checkbox" class="moderators" name="move" value="moderators" checked>
            <input type="checkbox" class="invited" name="move" value="invited" checked>
          </div> 
        </div>
```

The first row starts at position 2 which I think I can easily mark in CSS. But How do I make sure all of the inputs and labels are even spaced?

Thank you

Kevin

Comment: If you have a current version with css, can you provide a code snipped?

Comment: Your structure does look like a table. Is there a reason for not using one?

Comment: Well I was remembering that tables were often discouraged for styling. Does that not apply to this sort of case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox to get the result you want.

You are probably having some issues to do an error in your HTML.

In the top of your html you close a div tag early.

```html
<div class="column_labels"></div> <!-- EXTRA CLOSING DIV TAG HERE -->
  <label>All Members</label>
  <label>Relevant Experience</label>
  <label>HUB Moderators</label>
  <label>Invited Members</label>
</div>
```

```css
.permissions_grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.permissions_grid > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.permissions_grid > div > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=permissions_grid>
  <div>
    <label></label>
    <label>All Members</label>
    <label>Relevant Experience</label>
    <label>HUB Moderators</label>
    <label>Invited Members</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Edit Documents</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="all-D" name="edit_docs" value="all">
    <input type="checkbox" class="relevant" name="edit_docs" value="relevant">
    <input type="checkbox" class="moderators" name="edit_docs" value="moderators">
    <input type="checkbox" class="invited" name="edit_docs" value="invited" checked>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Add Feedback Categories</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="all-C" name="add_cat" value="all" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" class="relevant" name="add_cat" value="relevant">
    <input type="checkbox" class="moderators" name="add_cat" value="moderators">
    <input type="checkbox" class="invited" name="add_cat" value="invited">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Move Comments and Categories</label>
    <span class="x">X</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="relevant" name="move" value="relevant">
    <input type="checkbox" class="moderators" name="move" value="moderators" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" class="invited" name="move" value="invited" checked>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha that extra div tag messed up my entire page for like 30 minutes while I was trying to figure it out! I will give this a shot, Thanks!

Comment: It worked! I am trying to get the things to line up nicely now. How would I select just the column labels div to align the text right and the other labels to stick to the bottom?

Comment: To get the labels to align to the right, do `.permissions_grid > div:first-child {text-align:right}`

Comment: Hmm... that does the top row. I tried selecting .column_labels > label but it didn't work. Also vertical align and text align didn't get the top row to stick to the bottom of their cells